# How big could REG_BINARY be in Windows Registry?

Tags: windows, registry

I checked the windows documentation, REG_BINARY is binary data in any form. And I checked the size limit, it doesn't have a size limit itself. But the registry element has limit (Available memory (latest format)1 MB (standard format), https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-element-size-limits).

what is the latest format and standard format here? does this mean the REG_BINARY could be big like 1MB? Is there real big REG_BINARY example in Windows?

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-rprn/25cce700-7fcf-4bb6-a2f3-0f6d08430a55
                    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-element-size-limits

Comment: The doco also says data bigger then 2K should be stored in a file with a registry pointer to it instead in order to prevent registry bloat.  So  why test your luck with bigger?

Comment: Yes, the doc suggests that but it is not a hard limit. What I want to do is to read the REG_BINARY data and convert it, I have a concern that probably not all customers follow the suggestion. So I was wondering if there are real example with big REG_BINARY, and how big REG_BINARY could be in these examples.

Comment: What (lanugage) do you want to read it with?  What are you wanting to convert it to?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-storage-space